# How can I generate a permutation of a list of lists while maintaining order on the highest level in Python?

Tags: python, list, permutation

I am looking for a simple way to solve this. 
Lets say I have a list of lists, of which there are an uncertain number of lists in those lists:

```
lists = [
         [[1,2,3,4],[2,3,4,5]],
         [[1,2,3,4],[2,3,4,5],[3,4,5,6]],
         [[1,2,3,4]],
         [[1,2,3,4],[2,3,4,5]]
         ]
```

What I can't figure out is now to generate a permutation of all possible combinations while keeping the first level of `lists` in the same order. I have messed around with nested `for` loops and the `any()` function with little success. The nested for loops do not work, because in reality, `len(lists)` is much larger, and would take `len(lists)` amount of `for` loops. Does anyone have any ideas?

In the above example, a few possible permutations would be:

```
[[1,2,3,4],
 [1,2,3,4],
 [1,2,3,4],
 [1,2,3,4]]

[[1,2,3,4],
 [1,2,3,4],
 [1,2,3,4],
 [2,3,4,5]]

[[2,3,4,5],
 [1,2,3,4],
 [1,2,3,4],
 [2,3,4,5]]

[[2,3,4,5],
 [3,4,5,6],
 [1,2,3,4],
 [2,3,4,5]]
```

Comment: Those don't look like permutations to me; the order doesn't seem to change. It looks more like you want to take the Cartesian product, in which case this is a duplicate of many `itertools.product` questions.

Comment: @DSM you are absolutely right. This is especially embarrassing because of my physics background. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @DSM suggests, you may be looking for the **cartesian product**. Permutations means something different.

```
>>> import pprint, itertools as it
>>> lists = [
...          [[1,2,3,4],[2,3,4,5]],
...          [[1,2,3,4],[2,3,4,5],[3,4,5,6]],
...          [[1,2,3,4]],
...          [[1,2,3,4],[2,3,4,5]]
...          ]
>>> pprint.pprint(list(it.product(*lists)))
[([1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4]),
 ([1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4, 5]),
 ([1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4]),
 ([1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4, 5]),
 ([1, 2, 3, 4], [3, 4, 5, 6], [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4]),
 ([1, 2, 3, 4], [3, 4, 5, 6], [1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4, 5]),
 ([2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4]),
 ([2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4, 5]),
 ([2, 3, 4, 5], [2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4]),
 ([2, 3, 4, 5], [2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4, 5]),
 ([2, 3, 4, 5], [3, 4, 5, 6], [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4]),
 ([2, 3, 4, 5], [3, 4, 5, 6], [1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4, 5])]
```